# Coding guidlines for Controller and Dao?

Tags: java, mvc, coding-style, coding-standards, coding

My `Controller` code:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
ObjectReader objectReader = objectMapper.reader(User.class);
.....
....
response.setData(userControllerDao.updateUserDao(user, id));
```

My Dao code:

```
public List<User> updateUserDao(String userName) {
 if(! userName.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
        String split[] = userName.split(",");
        for(String s: split){
            userInfoQuery.field(Constant.USER_ID).equal(s.toString());
        }
    }
......
return;
```

I am little bit confused here in coding guidlines. As per `MVC` architecture I should have write `business logic` in controller. What about this `splitting` / `null checking` query in `Dao`? They should have move to `Controller` side?

If yes, then I still need to pass a `List` / `String` in `Dao` and split it again here. Does it make any sense to move them to Controller side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DAO code goes into the **Model,** not the controller.  DAO code is actually *farther away* from the controller than the business logic, and that logic doesn't go into the controller either.

Write a layer that contains methods that convert CRUD operations (Create, Read, Update, Delete) into DAO operations. Call the newly-created CRUD methods from your controller instead of the DAO code.

If you need something that maps closer to business operations, write another layer that contains methods that encompass actual business operations (such as TransferMoney, ReconcileInvoice or BuildWidget), and call your CRUD methods from this layer.

When you are done, it should look something like this:

```
Database <--> DAO Code <--> CRUD methods <--> Business Logic <--> Controller <--> View 
|---------------------- MODEL -----------------------------|
```

Everything to the left of the controller is the **Model.**  The only thing the controller does is decide which business domain methods to call.